# Drupal Paragraphs module - remove extra markup

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, paragraphs

I would like to remove the extra markup that is around the generated paragraph items.

```
<h1>
  <div class="field field-name-field-title field-type-text field-label-hidden">
    <div class="field-items">
      <div class="field-item even">Title</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</h1>
```

I would like it to display like this:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
```

I’ve not had any luck trying some of the suggestions in the Paragraphs issues https://www.drupal.org/node/2251909 such as editing the following files:

paragraphs-item.tpl.php
paragraphs-items.tpl.php
paragraphs.theme.inc

Does anyone have any experience with this module and be able to offer some assistance?

Comment: paragraphs-item.tpl.php should be the right file to edit. Did you copied that file to your theme in templates dir? Did you clear drupal's the cache after that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strip_tags()` to remove the html tags.

```
<h1><?php print strip_tags(render($content['YOUR_FIELD'])); ?></h1>
```

or

```
<?php print strip_tags(render($content['YOUR_FIELD']), "<h1>"); ?>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I was hoping to get rid of the code at source, that is being created by the module, but this does the job.